# Using the Swagger/Openapi to override a property shared between two schemas

Tags: inheritance, swagger, overriding, schema, openapi

I have 2 schemas (`UserDetails` & `UserDetails-Create`) with the difference between them being the description property of the `birth-date` field.

Is there a way to inherit all properties from `UserDetails` but override the description attribute on one of them?

I'm aware that you can modify the `required` attribute like this which is nifty:

```
UserDetails-Create:
      required:
      - name
      - age
      - birth-date
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserDetails'
```

Wondering if there is a shorthand way similar to the above that solves my problem?